# javax.ws.rs MediaType - Accept Header

Tags: rest, jax-rs, mime-types, media-type, javax.ws.rs

`@Consumes` as well as `@Produces`, both accepts the Media type. Accept Header in request corresponds to which annotation?

In most of the examples (e.g. [How to deal with accept-parameters when developing a jax-rs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997966/how-to-deal-with-accept-parameters-when-developing-a-jax-rs-application)) it shows of using `@Produces` to accept the Header from client request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Consumes` is for request type, i.e, the type the client is sending i.e. `Content-Type`. E.g.

```
@Consumes("application/json")
...
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: application/json
{ "json": "data" }

< 200 OK

@Consumes("application/json")
...
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: application/xml
<xml><data></data></xml>

> 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Here there are two example requests. On the server both are annotated with `@Consumes("application/json")`. This means that it can only handle data being sent in JSON format. The first request, the client send the data with correct `Content-Type`, so it gets an OK response. The second request, it sends XML data with a `Content-Type` not supported, so it gets a 415.

The `@Produces` is for the type of data sent by the server. The client can also add an `Accept` header to say what type it can accept (or process). If that type is not specified in the `@Produces`, then the server can't handle that type, and the client gets an error message. For example

```
@Produces("application/json")
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/json

< 200 OK
{ "json" : "data" }


@Produces("application/json")
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/xml

< 406 Not Acceptable
```